# Can you make Linux (Ubuntu) main hard disk read only? (live CD hard drive)

Tags: ubuntu, livecd

I have a Ubuntu system that has installed various program and custom stuff.

I would like to make it read-only so that against power interruption and other non-privileged user to damage it.

I think mount EXT4 as read only won't help, since it requires /var/log and /dev folder to be writable,

I was wondering can you make the existing system into a live CD harddisk (I.e. a live CD image into harddisk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount it read-only, and mount tmpfs to `/dev` and `/var/log`.

Comment: thanks, but is there any other folder need to be mounted as tempfs? /proc or ??

Comment: You could always try and find out.

Comment: `/dev` is *always* a tmpfs on udev-running Linux systems. Regarding `/proc`, it's already a *virtual* filesystem, too.

Comment: @grawity: "none on /dev type devtmpfs"

Comment: @c2h2: Typically, /proc is a proc type filesystem.

Comment: @Hello71: right, but devtmpfs is still a type of tmpfs, not affected by / being readonly.